# How isolation is achieved in isolated channel oscilloscopes?

Tags: oscilloscope, measurement, opto-isolator, isolation

I tried to search something about this but found only a small amount of information.

What confuses me is that all isolation amplifiers, optocouplers etc. I could find usually work at much lower frequencies than hundreds of MHz. So it is a mystery to me how the oscilloscopes work.

For example, here is some photos of Hantek DSO1152S
https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/hantek-dso1152s-wont-boot-after-firmware-update/100/
and DSO1122S
http://www.davidefabbri.net/files/foto/SANY0116.JPG

It is very difficult to understand from those photos how the isolation works. I only could find about DC-DC converters that seemingly used there
https://lib.chipdip.ru/503/DOC001503388.pdf

Comment: Do you have a high-resolution photo of the opposite side of the board?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I couldn't find it. Other photos of DSO1122S https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/hantek-tekway-dso-hack-get-200mhz-bw-for-free/msg433286/#msg433286 But that's only one side...

Comment: Update. There are some photos! I didn't see them earlier. https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/hantek-dso1152s-wont-boot-after-firmware-update/msg478323/#msg478323 and also link from that thread to a big zip file with photos http://www.taktik.co.nz/EEVBlog/Hantek-DSO1152S-Pics.zip Some chips are scratched, unfortunately. Some short info about ST-L6801 transformer http://sumlink.com.cn/PDF/FC01.pdf and some notes about the transformer and other chips from another thread https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/hantek-tekway-dso-hack-get-200mhz-bw-for-free/msg500813/#msg500813

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you're going to find a transformer in the signal path. Some methods use an optocoupler plus a transformer to handle DC-high frequency, and some modulate the input (which can then go down to DC), pass it through a transformer then demodulate after isolation.

The photos you linked appear to show a transformer and optoisolators on the bottom of the board, with a canned cheap DC-DC on the top of the board to supply power. Probably not the best isolation.

Comment: It would appear the DC/DC brick can isolate to 1500V (Mornsun WRA series). Out of curiosity, what would you say that this isolation scheme is lacking?

Comment: Pretty low isolation impedance. There's 85pF in the DC-DC alone and more from that blue safety rated  capacitor (and the transformer, and the opto and stray). Possibly a fair bit of noise current from the DC-DC too, so again if the isolated "ground" in the signal you are measuring isn't low impedance to earth you may see artifacts.

Comment: I can speak from experience that those DC/DC bricks usually aren't the quietest. I've had more than one EMI headache caused by them.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany Oh, didn't expect transformer (because I thought transformers usually have relatively narrow frequency range). Thank you. I wonder, what kind of modulation is usually used in that case. Maybe FM?
Also, those (DSO1xxxS) are probably among the cheapest isolated oscilloscopes out there, so...

Comment: Btw, here is approximate capacitance between channels (between "grounds" of channels) of Fluke 199C. Something around 29 pF.
https://imgur.com/a/10HpMDF
I know, not a good way of measuring low values of capacitance. Just a rough estimation.

Comment: @Dmitry 29pF is pretty good.  As far as modulation, you can find a Tek patent on their method. Transformers can cover a very wide bandwidth if well designed- transmission line transformers are very impressive, and even without that, <<1MHz to >>100MHz is routine.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe my eyes. Is this a 2.2 nF capacitor? Didn't pay attention to that earlier http://i008.radikal.ru/1408/70/02c54d04bc45.jpg That's so bad... I wanted to buy one of those scopes. Now I'm not so sure.

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, I think so. That's likely needed to conduct the noise to earth from the cheap DC-DC. So at 1MHz.. 70 ohms or so. Not very isolated.

Answer (score 0):

The isolation is in the internal DC-DC converter for each channel.

The float voltage between Multimeter and [earth]Ground  1000V may be conservative due to external AC-DC isolation.

In the case of SANY0116.jpg ( cropped below ), the isolation is in the DC-DC converter provided by a MORNSUN hybrid IC for each of the two channels with the creepage distance around the analog circuit and >=2mm air gap between channels.

[image]

-  Wide input voltage range (2:1)
-  High efficiency up to 86%
-  Isolation voltage 1.5KVDC
-  Output short circuit protection (self-recovery)
-  Operating temperature range: -40℃ to +85℃

[Ref](https://www.mornsun-power.com/uploads/pdf/WRA_P-3WR2.pdf)
[image]

This 2W version is obsoleted by a 3W version.

Comment: This is the isolation for power. What about the data? Form low-resolution pictures it is unclear, which side the ADCs are located, but there is some interface. The interface is on the other side of this board. I deleted my answer because it is unclear whether the entire front end with ADC is isolated, or there is some analog path running up to 200 MHz. That is the question.